# How to change card status in Angular nebular?

Tags: angular, nebular

I am trying to make flip-card component to flip after button clicked
I tried the following but I am getting this error

> TS2322: Type '{ isFlipped: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

this is my code
flip-card.component.ts

> export class FlipCardComponent implements OnInit {   constructor() {}
>
> isFlipped: boolean = false;
>
> ngOnInit(): void {}
>
> login(): void {
> console.log('Clicked');
> this.isFlipped = true;
> }
> }

flip-card.component.html

> <nb-flip-card [showToggleButton]="false" [flipped]={isFlipped} >
>
> ###### Hello! Please indicate your name:
>
> <button nbButton fullWidth status="primary" (click)="login()">Let's chat!
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
> A nebula is an interstellar cloud of dust, hydrogen,
> helium and other ionized gases.
> Originally, nebula was a name for
> any diffuse astronomical object,
> including galaxies beyond the Milky Way.

I don't know what is the problem, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your template’s code by the next

```
nb-flip-card [showToggleButton]="false"
 [flipped]=“isFlipped”>
```